# How to convert a string to a range of valúes

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of ranges like that (approximately 200 ranges with numbers and letters)

```
1. 01WA1A – 99XL9Z    (696762 of combinations)
2. 01YA1A – 99ZZ9Z 
3. 01SW1A – 99TW9Z 
4. A0001F – Z9999F
```

How shall it be evaluated to see if a string is in a range

I think that I can have a regular expresion or convert the string to only Numbers and evaluate this, but i dont know how to do this. Also I'm not sure which is best for performance because i need to evaluate for each range.

An example for the range 01WA1A – 99XL9Z is:

Some input will be some of these values.

01WA1B , 01WA1C ,  01WA1D ... 01WA2A, 01WA2B ....  02WA1A , 02WA1B ... 02WB0A .... 99XL9Y , 99XL9Z

Comment: Share with us what you have tried and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: If I'm following what you're asking, then, yes regex may work.  [My answer on a conceptually similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25277710/2908724) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its necesary evaluate  diferent positions of the string.

```
01WA1A – 99XL9Z
```

CHANGE to separated items..

```
01-99
WA-XL  
1-9
A-Z
```

After For letters it's necesary convert it to an number, i use the equivalent Asscii.

```
WA   - XL
8765 - 8876  

A - Z
65-90
```

THE RANGES ARE FOR  01WA1A – 99XL9Z  are

```
01-99 /   8765- 8876 /   1-9/  65-90
```

if the user introduce 99WA1A only needs  convert it in separated ranges, and evaluate each range  separate it

```
99 / 8765 / 1 / 65
```

these numbers are the range of ?

```
01-99 /   8765- 8876  /  1-9 /  65-90
```

If acept, these value its correct.